# wxPython: StatusBar does NOT update with long help from wxToolBar

Tags: user-interface, macos, wxpython, toolbar, statusbar

I am creating a ToolBar within a wx.Frame **init** and setting the help string as follows:

```
def __init_(self,...):
   ...
   self.CreateStatusBar()
   tb = self.CreateToolBar(wx.TB_HORIZONTAL|wx.NO_BORDER|wx.TB_FLAT)
   tb.SetToolBitmapSize((32,32))
   tb.SetSize((-1,132))
   tb.AddTool(ID_CLASSIFIER, bmp, shortHelpString='Classifier', longHelpString='Launch Classifier')
   ...
   tb.Realize()
```

--yet when I mouseover the toolbar icons, the StatusBar does not get updated. I had the same problem when adding PlateButtons to the toobar instead of using AddTool.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Just tested this on Windows and it works. Turns out it's a Mac specific problem.  That said, I'm still looking for a solution.

Thanks,
-Adam

Answer (score 0):

I use AddLabelTool in my code and that does show the help text on the status bar:

```
toolbar.AddLabelTool(self.id, '', bitmap, wx.NullBitmap, self.kind, 
                     shortHelp=wx.MenuItem.GetLabelFromText(self.menuText),
                     longHelp=self.helpText)
```

Comment: Turns out that this doesn't work on my Mac either (OSX 10.5.8).  It's starting to look like I'll need to handle the mouse events.

Comment: What wxPython version are you using?